# gulp sourcemap is created but not working

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

**Styles**

styles.less

```
@import "one.less";
@import "two.less";
```

one.less

```
body { background:red; }
```

two.less

```
body { font-size: 12px; }
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.src('./src/assets/less/styles.less')
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
```

**result:** styles.css + styles.map.css are created but the map file doesn't load when i enter the web page (and also when i inspect "body" i see styles.css)

**Links**

gulp less - https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less
gulp-sourcemaps - https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps

I'm so frustrated, i'd appreciate any help. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You're "piping" to `less()` before initializing the sourcemap plugin, the right way is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.src('./src/assets/less/styles.less')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
  .pipe(less())//<<< between init and write
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
```

Comment: sigh.. you are right. even though im  new to gulp, this should make sense. thank you very much.

Comment: I am now also trying to minify it, so I'm using .pipe(minifyCSS()) - the file is  indeed minified but the same problem i mentioned happened again

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is what I should have used - https://github.com/radist2s/gulp-less-sourcemap

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I  wrote the code between `init` and `write` but still, the map does not load in the browser

```js
gulp.task('css-task',async function(){
    return gulp.src('project/public/sass/main.scss')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // init the source map
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public/css'))
            .pipe(livereload());
});
```

I added `loadMaps: true` to `sourcemaps.init()` and things worked well

```js
gulp.task('css-task',async function(){
    return gulp.src('project/public/sass/main.scss')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // init the source map 
            ...
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public/css'))
            .pipe(livereload());
});
```